# Center Text Vertically Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, text

I have this little script. 
How can I center the text vertically? In another words, I need to bring out a variable from the function "wrapText" in order to use it to calculate the position of the text. Thanks a lot!

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="600" style="display:none;"></canvas>
<img id="canvasImg">

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function()
{
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
}  

imageObj.src = "img/imagea.jpg"; 

var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e)

{
    var text = document.getElementById('area1').value;

 if(text.lenght == 0)
    {
         alert("you forgot to put something");
    }



function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {

    var convtext = text.replace(/\n/g, ' |br| ');
    var words = convtext.split(' ');
    var line = '';

     for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
      var newline = false;
    if (words[n].indexOf("|br|") > -1) newline = true;

    var metrics = maxWidth;
    var testWidth = maxWidth;
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';

    if (context.measureText) {
    metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    testWidth = metrics.width;
    }

    if ((testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) || newline) {
    context.fillText(line, x, y);
    if (!newline) line = words[n] + ' ';
    if (newline) line = "";
    y += lineHeight;
    } else {
    line = testLine;
    }

    }

    context.fillText(line, x, y);

  }


  var maxWidth = 500;
  var lineHeight = 40;
  var x = 100;
  var y = 100;


 context.font = "30pt HelveticaNeue-Light";
 wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight);
 context.fillStyle = "#009bdc";
 context.fillText("try", 100, 500);


  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

  document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;

    e.preventDefault();


});

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Here's how:**

1. Modify `wrapText` to return the ending `height` value (so you can calculate the paragraph height).
2. Modify `wrapText` to optionally not draw (==optionally, not do `fillText`)
3. Run `wrapText` once in the no-draw mode to get the height of the wrapped paragraph.
4. Calculate a starting `y` that will produce a vertically centered paragraph: `var centeringY = maxHeight/2 - paragraphHeight/2`
5. Run `wrapText` again in the yes-draw mode using `centeringY`.

**Example code and a Demo:**

*A paragraph of wrapped text that's vertically centered...*

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var maxWidth = 150;
var lineHeight = 20;
var x = 100;
var y = 100;
var text='It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness.';

context.font='12px verdana';

var height=wrapTextVCentered(context,text,x,y,maxWidth,lineHeight,true);

var y=(canvas.height-height)/2;

wrapTextVCentered(context,text,x,y,maxWidth,lineHeight,false);

context.strokeStyle='green';
context.strokeRect(x,y,maxWidth,height);

function wrapTextVCentered(context,text,x,y,maxWidth,lineHeight,measureOnly){
  var height=0;
  var convtext = text.replace(/\n/g, ' |br| ');
  var words = convtext.split(' ');
  var line = '';

  context.textBaseline='top';

  for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++){
    var newline = false;
    if (words[n].indexOf("|br|") > -1) newline = true;

    var metrics = maxWidth;
    var testWidth = maxWidth;
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';

    if (context.measureText){
      metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
      testWidth = metrics.width;
    }

    if ((testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) || newline){
      if(!measureOnly){ context.fillText(line, x, y); }
      if (!newline) line = words[n] + ' ';
      if (newline) line = "";
      y += lineHeight;
      height += lineHeight;
    } else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }
  if(!measureOnly){ context.fillText(line, x, y); }

  height += lineHeight;
  return(height);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Vertically centered paragraph on canvas</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
```